# Is it possible to use an FFT to remove noise from an image that is already characterised by another image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-learn, fft

I am trying to remove the impact/influence of image `A` (that contains a bunch of low frequency "smooth noise") from image `B` (that contains the feature I want - in this case a square).  I thought an FFT might be an interesting tool to use, but I'm not sure if they can be applied in this way, or if there is a better tool to use?

Is it possible to write a function `f(A, B) = C` given the inputs below:

[image: input data]

Comment: so C is desired, B is input, and A is an estimation of the "noise"? ... are you actually dealing with a "vignette"? that's not "low frequency noise". -- more details please. pictures are better than words. be specific, not abstract.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Can A (or the "vignette") be modelled as a low frequency component or is there not enough information?  Intuitively, I'd expect it to be `FFT(B) - FFT(A)` but that clearly doesn't work because `C` is brighter than both `A` and `B` (unless `ImageJ` is equalising the FFT outputs).

Comment: To get a bit more specific in this example `A` represents a heightfield and `B` is a feature on that heightfield.  `A` represents the a heightfield that should really be flat, but actually has a quadratic distortion on it (the vignette).

Comment: A+C does not equal B. if A only "applies to" background, then you could argue that A + C = B, but then you'd have to know what's background from just B (and maybe A, if you're sure you have that). -- addition ought to be the same in state space and frequency space (sum of sines, sum of spectra), is my intuition anyway. the square in B would have to be brighter than 1 (possible, but not the case here). anyway, fouriers here sounds silly. if this is a class assignment and you *must* do as the teacher says, I don't see the point.

Comment: So to make `A + C = B` the square would have to be brighter (or the vignette darker)?  Is there somewhere I can read about the "state space and frequency space" to determine if I can add and subtract in these spaces?  I am doing this for my own interest rather than a class assignment or anything :)

Comment: "fourier transform properties" would yield some useful facts like table 4.2 on https://www.princeton.edu/~cuff/ele201/kulkarni_text/frequency.pdf. start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem, which is the most interesting property (goes both ways). other properties are useful but less interesting. your case would be "linearity" (addition and scaling, where scaling is a "multiplication" that's different from multiplication of signals). this is a math/DSP topic so you'll get better answers on stack exchanges specific to those.

Comment: Thanks very much for your insight and replies Christoph - as somebody who does not do so much maths day to day, I really value what you have shared with me. :)